# How to use metadata annotation to provide a warning message in Dart analyzer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a metadata annotation like this:

```dart
class UseInt {
  const UseInt();
}

@UseInt()
class Foo {
  // Should give a lint warning saying "The class should only use ints".
  String message = ''; 
}
```

As you may have seen, inbuilt Dart and Flutter metadata gives you a warning message when you try to do something against what was originally meant, something like this:

[image]

How can I make the IDE do something like this in my original code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit 2 (Macros)

Although macros are not yet a part of the Dart specification (and are really meant for code generation), you could actually use them here for type checking (and could be used to prevent compilation!). In your example, `UseInt` would be a phase 3 macro on a class:

```dart
macro class UseInt implements ClassDefinitionsMacro {
  const UseInt();

  @override
  Future<void> buildDefinitionForClass(
      ClassDeclaration clazz, ClassDefinitionBuilder builder) async {
    final fields = await builder.fieldsOf(class);

    for (final field in fields) {
       final type = await builder.resolve(field.type.code);
       final isInt = false; // TODO probably could be done with something like type.isSubtypeOf but I haven't figured out the best way to do this yet
       assert(isInt, '$field in $clazz is not of type int!');
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about macros here: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/working/macros/feature-specification.md

### Edit (Plugins)

I forgot that you can actually create an analyzer/linter plugin. See here: https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/tree/master/packages/riverpod_lint

And here:

https://pub.dev/packages/custom_lint

### Original Answer

This is very non-trivial.

I dug through the source of a few different packages a little and it looks like you might be able to make a fork of the [linter](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter) and define your own custom rule for `UseInt`. There are plenty of examples; for example, you can see how `avoid_print` is defined [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/blob/main/lib/src/rules/avoid_print.dart).

However, the screenshot you gave uses [`must_be_immutable`](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#must_be_immutable), which is [actually defined in the analyzer itself](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/search?q=must_be_immutable). If a custom rule from the linter cannot achieve what you want here, you might need to instead fork the [analyzer](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/main/pkg/analyzer) and create your own [Diagnostic message](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages) in your fork of the analyzer.

Comment: I thought how by just adding `@immutable`, I get a warning, I could also create something like it easily.

Comment: It doesn’t look like it is that easy unfortunately. You’d have to make some noteworthy code modifications

Comment: @iDecode I am not sure if you have seen my edits, but right now you could do what you are asking with the `custom_lints` package. In the future, you could use macros to prevent compilation using a macro (see my unfinished example)